# Sigma 10-20mm f5.6 alternatives?

Tags: lens, nikon, cropped-sensor, sigma, wide-angle

I've been wanting to add a wide angle lens to my collection for a while now. Sigma 10-20mm f5.6 looks good. I was looking at it about 2 years ago. I was wondering if there have been newer wide angle lenses around the same price range. My budget is $500ish. I'm aware of the newer Sigma 10-20mm f3.5 but it's way over my price range. I have a Nikon D90.

Comment: Sigma has 10-20mm f/4-5.6 and 10-20mm f/3.5 lenses.

Comment: Oops, I meant 10-20mm, not 10-22mm. corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alternatives are:

- Nikon 10-24mm f3.5-4.5
- Nikon 12-24mm f4
- Tokina 11-16mm f2.8
- Tamron 10-24mm f3.5-4.5
- Sigma 10-22mm f3.5

If budget is your only consideration, Tamron seems to be the best fit.

Fullframe lenses like the Nikon 14-24mm f2.8 also exist, but these are much more expensive and bulky.

Comment: +1 for the Tokina.. I rented one for 2 week earlier this month and absolutely loved it..

Comment: Yeah, the Tokina is just the perfect wide angle for the DX format for my point of view. f/2.8 is very useful for inside and the price is still acceptable even a bit higher than the 500$ but it worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Another consideration is the Sigma 8-16mm.

Comment: The Sigma 8-16 is amazing, and sharper than the 10-20.  It may also be out of his price range though.

Answer (score 1):

DPReview has looked at both lenses and found them both to be of good quality, albeit with their individual pros/cons.  Have a look through the reviews and sample images:

http://www.dpreview.com/lensreviews/sigma_10-20_4-5p6_n15/
http://www.dpreview.com/lensreviews/tamron_10-24_3p5-5p6_n15/

Personally though, seeing as there's so little in it, I'd just get whichever I can find for the best deal!  I picked up the Sigma f4-5.6 second hand for £250 earlier this year and have been very pleased with the results.

Answer (score 1):

I got the sigma 10-20 f5.6 several months a ago. And haven't taken it off since. I love the look of the photos, esecially shots of my kid messing around. Also great for interior photography where there isn't much room, although I often need to bounce my speedlite as the lens isn't particularly fast.