# Wide angle lenses for cheap bodies around 500USD

Tags: wide-angle, nikon-d3100

I own a basic **nikon d3100** camera. Want to buy a wide angle lens which can auto focus on my camera. Any suggestions??? Focal Length should be from 10mm.

Comment: Use the search feature of a major online photo retailer. Like this: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Lens+Types+for+APS-C+Cameras_Wide+Zoom&ci=274&N=4288584247+4108103566+4109119987+4291315846+4291220258+38+4109119986&mxp=550

Comment: Presumably you have the kit 18-55 lens. Should we assume that 18 isn't wide enough? Is there something you can't do with the current lens that could turn this into a better question that people can better help with?

Comment: Could you give a little more requirements than AF and wide. There are hundreds of lenses that fit this spec (1 of which you own). What situation have you been in that the kit lens wasn't enough?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/sigma-10-20mm-f5-6-alternatives

Comment: @HareshKannan - it is still completely unclear what you are asking.  The way you currently have it worded, simply searching for wide angle lenses on any retailer would give you as much detail as we can give you.  We'd need details what you want to do with it (at a minimum) to have any hope of being able to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the pretty good sigma 10-20mm EX HSM (fast focus) within your budget. The corners are a bit mushy at 10mm but it is a fun lens to use:

[http://www.amazon.com/Sigma-10-20mm-4-5-6-Digital-Cameras/dp/B0007U00XK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007U00XK)

http://www.photozone.de/nikon--nikkor-aps-c-lens-tests/467-sigma_1020_35_nikon?start=2